# How to prevent a double "let us continue this discussion in chat" comment?

Tags: feature-request, chat, automatic-comments

... in order to prevent two simultaneous chats being created.

Yesterday, I got the orange *"Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"* -box in commenting on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635374/vertically-centering-an-image-with-max-height-and-max-width/6635411#6635411). (Sorry, all relevant comments are deleted, but maybe admins can still see them.)

So I started that chat, but the other arguer also started a chat which resulted in two separate chats.

It seems the orange box appears for both parties of the discussion. Sounds logical. But as soon as one of them uses that option, should that orange box not dissappear or change into:

> *[Other name] moved this discussion to chat. Would you like to follow?*

for the second party, to prevent double chats?

Answer (score 10):

This is usually prevented by using the fact that room name and topic are auto-generated, and can't be changed by the users (because they're not owners). This was the simplest thing possible and suffices in 99% of the cases. It failed here because the other user recently changed their display name, and when the first room was created, chat still had the old name, but by the time the second one was created, their chat profile had been updated.

I'll have a look at storing this information in a less volatile way.

Comment: does this really need to be fixed? It seems this is kind of an extreme edge condition if it's predicated on one user changing their name.

Comment: +1 For already dealing with it. Just for curiosity: what ís the default preventing behavior? Does the second click result in showing the chat of the first? Or?

Comment: Could the unique chat room name not be generated already at showing the orange box, rather then on clicking? Make the room name part of the link.

Comment: Same [extreme edge condition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106992/dont-add-would-you-like-to-automatically-move-this-discussion-to-chat-when-t)?

Comment: @NGLN: Shouldn't; the issue I'm describing here shouldn't occur anymore. I'll check, though.