# Don't add, "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" when the discussion has been already moved in chat from the other user

Tags: feature-request, chat

In [Using hook_theme_registry_alter to only modify specific pages instead of all pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11683/using-hook-theme-registry-alter-to-only-modify-specific-pages-instead-of-all-page/11698#11698), the other user already moved the discussion on chat, but the message (shown after the comment that is automatically added) still asks if I want to move it.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to prevent a double “let us continue this discussion in chat” comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98035/how-to-prevent-a-double-let-us-continue-this-discussion-in-chat-comment)