# Moving a comments thing twice to chat

Tags: bug, chat, automatic-comments

I recently helped a user out, and decided to move it to chat. When I went back to the question and read over the comments, I noticed I could move it over to chat again. Shouldn't this be disabled once it's been moved?

[image]

Update: It does not recreate a chatroom or create another comment, but rather simply takes you to the existing room. It still should not be displaying that message, though.

Comment: Did you try to add the comment? Was it added?

Comment: That won't bump the thread. Also, a duplicate exists. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98035/212576